# When are new objects created in JavaScript's constructor function vs in class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

### Constructor Function

When creating a new object via a good old ES5 constructor function: When is the new object created?

**A guess**: Is it created immediately when the JS engine encounters the `new` keyword, directly before the constructor function is executed?

---

### Class

Similarly to above, but for classes: When is the new object created?

**A guess**: Since we can subclass built-in objects with `class` syntax, I am thinking the engine must know what type (`exotic` vs `ordinary`) its parent object is. Therefore, I was thinking perhaps the new object is created right when the engine encounters the `extends` keyword and can read what type the parent is.

---

### Lastly

In both cases, when is the prototype property set? Is it before or after executing the constructor function / ClassBody?

---

### Notes

**Note 1**: It would be great if the answer could include links to where in the [ECMAScript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0) each of the two creations occur. I have been searching around a lot and have been unable to find the right algorithm-steps.

**Note 2**: With "created" I mean space allocated in memory and type set (exotic vs ordinary), at a minimum.

Comment: @JaromandaX. It is not exactly just syntactic sugar. For instance: 1) With classes we inherit static properties; 2) With classes we are able to create exotic objects, when extending other exotic objects (like Array). This enables us to extend exotic built-ins in a way not before possible. Therefore, I think there must be a timing difference in when the new object is created. The following article alludes to it: https://www.sitepoint.com/object-oriented-javascript-deep-dive-es6-classes/

Comment: So you don't have to read it all @JaromandaX : "ES6 classes fixed this by changing when and by whom objects are allocated....". That paragraph mentions it. I just want to see it myself, from the ECMAScript spec.

Comment: _Therefore, I was thinking perhaps the new object is created right when the engine encounters the `extends` keyword and can read what type the parent is._ This is completely wrong. A `class` declaration does not instantiate an object, the `new` operator does.

Comment: @JaromandaX . If you take a look at at the SitePoint article I linked, when setting the prototype of an ES5 constructor function to `Object.create(Array.prototype)`, the constructor function will produce an `ordinary` object, not an `exotic` object. That behavior differs from how `extend` works. I might of course be missing some feature of ES5 that I have not yet come across.

Comment: the SitePoint example is flawed. `class` syntax when transpiled, becomes `function D () { return Array.apply(this, arguments) }` note the `return`, which is necessary for the exotic behavior.

Comment: of course, transpiling doesn't necessarily give 100% identical functionality ... you can transpile `const constant = 1` fine, but you can't transpile `const constant = 1; constant = 2;` because the transpiler "spots" the error ...however, there's nothing stopping you in transpiled code to overwrite `constant` later - whereas in an ES6 engine, a const remains constant - so, referring to trasnpiled version is not necessarily 100% identical in function :p (which is why I removed my previous comments)

Comment: still however - why is the exact moment of object instantiation important?

Comment: but still, the points in the (now) first comment are not valid - you can use ES5 syntax (in an ES6 engine) and still achieve both of those points (inherit static properties and extending built-in objects) - the class syntax hasn't given us these things, it's just made them far easier to implement

Comment: I can't think of any use-case for knowing the exact moment of instantiation; the whole point of requiring `super()` before any reference to `this` is to make the exact moment transparent to userland. I strongly suspect that the point of instantiation is therefore implementation-dependent.

Comment: Thanks gents. I would like to understand the inner workings of the language, and particularly how to read it out of the official spec, in order to improve as a developer. Were you able to figure out where in the spec it happens? It should be under `[[Call]]`, `[[Construct]]`, or `FunctionCreate`, but I am struggling finding it. To your point on extending built-ins JaromandaX, of course we could extend built-ins before, but the point is what happens when trying to extend an `exotic` object and wanting to get an `exotic` object in return.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks. Regarding your comment on `return`, how exactly does that work? I mean, how does the class know that `this` should be an `exotic` object whenever the parent is `exotic`? If it is clear to you, could you perhaps post an answer?

Comment: `this !== Array.apply(this, arguments)`. Regarding the syntactic sugar we refer to as `super()`, the specification states that when the subclass constructor returns a different reference, `this` _becomes_ that reference, which is why `super()` must be called before referencing `this` because in ES5, the `this` no longer refers to the initialized exotic object as the SitePoint example and my counter-example demonstrated.

Comment: My understanding which may be flawed (and I'll have to look closer at the specification to clarify), is that in ES5, construction of the `D` function with the `return` statement results in two instantiated objects: a discarded reference created by the `new` operator, and the exotic object that is returned by the `Array` subclass. In ES6, either the subclass is defined to be responsible for instantiating, OR it's implementation-dependent as to what exactly occurs. Since `super()` determines what `this` refers to in an ES6 `class`, that's why I suspect it's the latter.

Comment: I guess you are looking for https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget ?

Comment: @FelixKling Hi Felix. I have spent some time working my way from your link (e.g. searching for all places that `[[Construct]]` is called from), and among some other un-related places, `[[Construct]]` of a new object happens **both** when `new Foo(..)` is evaluated, **and** when `super(..)` is evaluated. For `super()` it somehow gets parent constructor I think, with `12.3.5.2 GetSuperConstructor()`, but not sure I understand how. It then uses that constructor to create a new object. Link: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-super-keyword-runtime-semantics-evaluation.

Comment: ....Despite all that, I still do not understand how that new object created by super makes `class` work differently than `constructor function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`new`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-evaluatenew) will call [Construct](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-construct), which in turn will call the related function's internal [[[Construct]]](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget). I will only discuss the normal [[Construct]] here, and not care about e.g. Proxies having custom behavior for it, as that is imho not related to the topic.

---

In the standard scenario (no `extends`), in step 5.a, [[Construct]] calls [OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ordinarycreatefromconstructor), and the return of that will be used as `this` (see [OrdinaryCallBindThis](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ordinarycallbindthis), where it is used as argument). Note that OrdinaryCallEvaluateBody comes at a later step - the object is created, before the constructor function is evaluated. For `new f`, it is basically `Object.create(f.prototype)`. Generally, it's `Object.create(newTarget.prototype)`. This is the same for `class` and the ES5 way. The prototype is obviously set there aswell.

---

The confusion probably stems from the case, where `extends` is being used. In that case, [[ConstructorKind]] is not "base" (see step 15 of [ClassDefinitionEvaluation](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation)), so in [[Construct]], step 5.a does not apply anymore, nor is OrdinaryCallBindThis called.  The important part here happens in the [super call](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-super-keyword-runtime-semantics-evaluation). Long story short, it calls Construct with the SuperConstructor and current newTarget, and binds the result as `this`. Accordingly, as you may know, any access to `this` before the super call results in an error. As such, the "new object" is created in the super call (note that the discussed applies again to that call to Construct - should the SuperConstructor not extend anything, the non-deriving case, otherwise this one - with the only difference being newTarget).

To elaborate on the newTarget forwarding, here is an example of how this behaves:

```js
class A { constructor() { console.log(`newTarget: ${new.target.name}`); } }
class B extends A { constructor(){ super(); } }
console.log(
  `B.prototype's prototype: ${Object.getPrototypeOf(B.prototype).constructor.name}.prototype`
);
console.log("Performing `new A();`:");
new A();
console.log("Performing `new B();`:");
new B();
```

As [[Construct]] calls OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor with newTarget as parameter, which is always forwarded, the prototype used will be the correct one at the end (in above example, `B.prototype`, and note that this in turn has `A.prototype` as prototype, aka `Object.getPrototypeOf(B.prototype) === A.prototype`). It's good to look at all the related parts (super call, Construct, [[Construct]], and OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor), and watch how they get/set or pass newTarget along. Note here aswell that the call to PrepareForOrdinaryCall also gets the newTarget, and sets it in the FunctionEnvironment of related SuperConstructor calls, so that additional chained super calls will obtain the correct one aswell (for the case of extending from something that is in turn extending from something).

---

Last but least, constructors can use `return` to produce any object they want. This usually leads to the objects created in the previously described steps to be simply discarded. However, you can do the following:

```
const obj = {};
class T extends Number {
  constructor() {
    return obj;
  }
}
let awkward = new T();
```

In this very awkward case, there is no call to `super`, which is however also no error, as the constructor simply returns some previously made object. Here, at least from what i could see, no object will be created at all when using `new T()`.

There is another side effect. Should you extend from a constructor, which returns some self-made object, the forwarding of newTarget and all that has no effect, the prototype of the extending class is simply lost:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    // The created object still has the function here.
    // Note that in all normal cases, this should not
    // be in the constructor of A, it's just to show
    // what is happening.
    this.someFunc();
    //rip someFunc, welcome someNewFunc
    return {
      someNewFunc() { console.log("I'm new!"); }
    }; 
  }
}
class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
    //We get the new function here, after the call to super
    this.someNewFunc();
  }
  someFunc() { console.log("something"); }
}
console.log("Performing `new B();`:");
let obj = new B();
console.log("Attempting to call `someFunc` on the created obj:");
obj.someFunc(); // This will throw an error.
```

---

PS: I read a lot of this in the spec for the first time myself aswell, so there may be some mistakes. My own interest was to find out how extending built-ins works (stemming from a different debate from a while ago). To understand that, after the above, needs only one last thing: we notice e.g. for the [Number constructor](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-number-constructor-number-value), that it checks for "If NewTarget is undefined [...]", and otherwise properly calls OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor, with NewTarget, while adding the internal [[NumberValue]] slot, then setting it in the next step.

---

Edit to attempt answering questions in the comments:

I think you are still looking at `class` and the ES5 way as two separate things. `class` is almost entirely syntactic sugar, as has already been mentioned in comments on the question. A class is nothing more than a function, similar to the "old ES5 way".

---

Towards your first question, the "method" you mention, is the function, which one would use in the ES5 way (and what the variable will hold, `class A extends Number {}; console.log(typeof A === "function" && Object.getPrototypeOf(A) === Number);`). The prototype is set, to achieve what you earlier noted as "inheriting static properties". Static properties are nothing more than properties on the constructor (if you ever used the ES5 way).

The [[HomeObject]] is used for access to `super`, as explained in [table 27](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#table-27). If you look at what the related calls do (see [table 27](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#table-17), [GetSuperBase](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-getsuperbase)), you will notice it, in essence, just does "[[HomeObject]].[[GetPrototypeOf]]()". That will be the superclass prototype, as it should be, so that `super.someProtoMethod` works on the superClass' prototype.

---

For the second question, i think it's best to just go through an example:

```
class A { constructor() { this.aProp = "aProp"; } }
class B extends A { constructor() { super(); this.bProp = "bProp"; }
new B();
```

I'll try to list the interesting steps, performed in order, when `new B();` is being evaluated:

- `new` calls Construct, which, as there is no current newTarget, calls [[Construct]] of `B` with newTarget now set to `B`.
- [[Construct]] encounters a kind which is not "base", and as such does not create any object
- PrepareForOrdinaryCall, for the execution of the constructor, generates a new execution context, along with a new FunctionEnvironment (where [[NewTarget]] will be set to newTarget!), and makes it the running execution context.
- OrdinaryCallBindThis is also not performed, and `this` stays uninitialized
- OrdinaryCallEvaluateBody will now start executing the constructor of `B`
- The super call is encountered and executed:

  - GetNewTarget() retrieves the [[NewTarget]] from the FunctionEnvironment, which was previously set
  - Construct is called on the SuperConstructor, with the retrieved newTarget
  - It calls [[Construct]] of the SuperConstructor, with the newTarget
  - The SuperConstructor has kind "base", as such it performs OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor, but with the newTarget set. This is now in essence `Object.create(B.prototype)`, and note again, that `Object.getPrototypeOf(B.prototype) === A.prototype`, that's already set on the function `B`, from the class construction.
  - Similarly to above, a new execution context is being made, and this time, OrdinaryCallBindThis is also done. The SuperConstructor will execute, produce some object, the execution context is popped again. Note that should `A` in turn extend something else again, newTarget is properly set everywhere again, so it would just go deeper and deeper.
  - super takes the result from Construct (the object that the SuperConstructor produced, which does have `B.prototype` as prototype, should nothing exceptional happen - as discussed, e.g. the constructor returns some other value, or the prototype was manually changed), and sets it as `this` in the current environment, which is the one that is used to execute the constructor of `B` (the other has been popped already).
- execution of the constructor of `B` continues, with `this` now initialized. It is an Object, which has `B.prototype` as prototype, which in turn has `A.prototype` as prototype, and on which the `A` constructor was already called (again, should nothing exceptional have happened), so `this.aProp` already exists. The constructor of `B` will then add `bProp`, and that object is the result of `new B();`.

Comment: Incredibly helpful Gerte, thank you very much! I will work my way through and revert with any questions.

Comment: First question: Within ClassDefinitionEvaluation (14.5.13), step 12 seems to define a new method which has a prototype property set to the superclass, and [[HomeObject]] set to an empty object linking to superclass.prototype. Is that right? What is that new method supposed to represent? As seen in step 14, that entire new method is returned from ClassDefinitionEvaluation.

Comment: Second question: When executing super() from constructor method (12.3.5.1), we start with GetNewTarget(). If I understand correctly, GetNewTarget first gets the `this` environment, which is the Environment Record for the new function environment created by execution context when it entered the constructor method. I am still not sure what envRec.[[NewTarget]] equals though, because [[NewTarget]] is what was set on environment record when [[Construct]] was called, but it has not been called yet (unless it refers to [[Construct]] by `new` (as opposed to `super`).

Comment: @Magnus i edited the answer. Note again, that i also only read those spec parts yesterday/today, so i hope no inaccuracies or mistakes sneaked in :)

Comment: Towards downvoter: I am aware i may have made some mistakes, but if that is the case, please explain them. If there are downvotes without any further explanation on such a topic, i'll have to just ignore them.

Comment: Thanks again. I have spent some time going through it all. To confirm: 14.5.13 ClassDefinitionEvaluation returns a new *class constructor* function, **not** the class object itself right? With *class constructor* function, I mean the method inside the class, named *constructor*. Secondly, in the same algorithm, step 6.b., does "result of evaluating ClassHeritage" mean that the entire algorithm (14.5.13) is run again for the parent class, and that *superclass* then actually equals the constructor method inside the parent class, rather than the whole class object itself?

Comment: Never mind, I got it. When `class className {..}` is evaluated (starts at 14.5.15: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-class-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation), it is the *constructor* method from within the class which is stored in the environment record (see 14.5.14), not the class itself. So, at step 6.b. in 14.5.13 (ClassDefinitionEvaluation): Evaluating ClassHeritage will result in superclass being set to constructor method of parent class (not the class itself). Note: This is also why parent classes always must be defined above child classes in the source code.

Answer (score 2):

> When creating a new object via a good old ES5 constructor function: When is the new object created?

The spec-level definition of object construction behavior is defined by the `[[Construct]]` function. For standard JS functions (`function Foo(){}`, the definition of this function is initialized in [9.2.3 FunctionAllocate](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-functionallocate) where `functionKind` will `"normal"`. Then you can see on step `9.a`, the `[[Construct]]` slot is declared to point at [section 9.2.2](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget) and `[[ConstructorKind]]` is set to `"base"`.

When user code calls `new Foo();` to construct an instance of this function, it will call from [12.3.3 The `new` operator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-new-operator) to [12.3.3.1.1 EvaluateNew](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-evaluatenew) to [7.3.13 Construct](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-construct) to `[[Construct]]`, which calls the slot initialized above, passing the arguments, and the `Foo` function as `newTarget`.

Digging into [9.2.2 `[[Construct]]`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget), we can see that step `5.a` performs:

> 5. a. Let `thisArgument` be ? `OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor(newTarget, "%ObjectPrototype%")`.

which answers your question of *when*. The `this` object is created here by essentially doing `Object.create(Foo.prototype)` (with a little extra ignorable logic in there). The function will then continue along and at step `8` it will do

> 8. If kind is `"base"`, perform `OrdinaryCallBindThis(F, calleeContext, thisArgument)`.

which you can kind of think of as doing `this = thisArgument`, which will set the value of `this` in the function, before it actually calls the logic of the `Foo` function on step `11`.

The primary difference for ES6 classes vs ES5-style constructor functions is that the `[[Construct]]` methods are only used once, at the *first* level of construction. For example, if we have

```
function Parent(){}
function Child(){
  Base.apply(this, arguments);
}
Object.setPrototype(Child.prototype, Parent.prototype);

new Child();
```

the `new` will use `[[Construct]]` for `Child`, but the call to `Parent` uses `.apply`, meaning that it isn't actually constructing the parent, it's just calling it like a normal function and passing along an appropriate `this` value.

This is where things become complicated, as you've noticed, because it means that `Parent` doesn't actually have any influence over the creation of `this`, and just has to hope that it is given an acceptable value.

> Similarly to above, but for classes: When is the new object created?

The main difference with ES6 class syntax is that because the parent function is called with `super()` instead of `Parent.call`/`Parent.apply`, the `[[Construct]]` function of parent functions is called rather than `[[Call]]`. Because of this, it's actually possible to get into [9.2.2 `[[Construct]]`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget) with `[[ConstructorKind]]` set to something other than `"base"`. It's this change in behavior that affects when the object is constructed.

If we revisit our example above now, with ES6 classes

```
class Parent {
  constructor() {
  }
}
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

`Child` is not `"base"`, so when the `Child` constructor initially runs, the `this` value is uninitialized. You can kind of think of `super()` as doing `const this = super();`, so just like

```
console.log(value);
const value = 4;
```

would throw an exception, because `value` had not been initialized yet, it is the call to `super()` that calls the parent `[[Construct]]`, and then initializes the `this` inside of the `Child` constructor function body. The parent `[[Construct]]` behaves just like it would in ES5 if it were `function Parent(){}`, because `[[ConstructorKind]]` is `"base"`.

This behavior is also what allows ES6 class syntax to extend native types like `Array`. The call to `super()` is what actually creates the instance, and since the `Array` function knows all that it needs to know to create a real functional array, it can do so, and then return that object.

> In both cases, when is the prototype property set? Is it before or after executing the constructor function / ClassBody?

The other key piece that I glossed over above is the exact nature of `newTarget` mentioned above in the spec snippets. In ES6, there is a new concept that is the "new target", which is the actual constructor function passed to `new`. So if you do `new Foo`, you're actually using `Foo` in two different ways. One is that you're using the function as a constructor, but the other is that you're using that value as the "new target". This is critical for the nesting of class constructors, because when you call a chain of `[[Construct]]` functions, the actual constructor being called will work it's way up the chain, but the `newTarget` value will remain the same. This is important because `newTarget.prototype` is what is used to actually set the prototype of the final constructed object. For instance, when you do

```
class Parent extends Array {
  constructor() {
    console.log(new.target); // Child
    super();
  }
}
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log(new.target); // Child
    super();
  }
}
new Child();
```

The call to `new Child` will call the `Child` constructor, and also set it as the `newTarget` value to `Child`. Then when `super()` is called, we're using `[[Construct]]` from `Parent`, but also passing `Child` as the `newTarget` value still. This repeats for `Parent` and means that even though `Array` is responsible for creating an array exotic object, it can still use `newTarget.prototype` (`Child.prototype`) to ensure that the array has the correct prototype chain.

Comment: Thank you, Logan, deeply appreciated as always. I need to take some time to work through all this.